# First homology group of an abelian group

Tags: homology-cohomology, abelian-groups, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be an abelian group and $R$ a commutative ring , with trivial G-action on $R$, I am trying to see that $H_1(G,R) \cong H_1(G)\otimes R \cong G\otimes R$, so by definition if we wake a projective resolution $F$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}[G]$, we have that $H_1(G,R)=H_1(F\otimes_G R)$,  and now i have tried using something like the universal coefficient theorem but got nowhere. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know that $H_1(G,\mathbf{Z})=G$ if $G$ is an abelian group?

Comment: Yes, i belive that $H_1(G,Z)$ is the abelinization for an arbitary group $G$ , im just a little confused on how to use the universal coefficient theorem because we have that tensor product over $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the Universal Coefficient Theorem for Group homology is that it is just the UCT for modules over $\mathbf{Z}$ adapted to the case of $\mathbf{Z}[G].$

To make this work, note that you can start with a projective $\mathbf{Z}[G]$ resolution of $\mathbf{Z}$. So you have 
$$P_\bullet\to \mathbf{Z}$$ as $\mathbf{Z}[G]$ modules. Then you can tensor this with $-\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}[G]}R$ and note that you get a new complex $ P_\bullet\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}[G]}R$. The cohomology is defined as 
$$H_{*}(G,R)=H_{*}(P_\bullet\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}[G]}R) $$

However note that in case $R$ is a trivial $G$-module, we have $$P_\bullet\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}[G]}R\cong (\mathbf{Z}\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}[G]} P_\bullet) \otimes_{\mathbf{Z}}R.$$

So you can apply the UCT for chain complexes of $\mathbf{Z}$ modules here which gives
$$H_{i}(G,R)=H_{i}(G,\mathbf{Z})\oplus \textrm{Tor}_1^{\mathbf{Z}}(H_{i-1}(G,\mathbf{Z}),R).$$

The general result now is that $H_1(G,R)=G/[G,G]\otimes R$ whenever $R$ is a trivial $G$ module, since the Tor term vanishes as $H_0(G,\mathbf{Z})=\mathbf{Z}$ is flat over itself. 
The point is that the UCT for Group Homology only works in the case $R$ is a trivial $\mathbf{Z}[G]$ module, for then the coinvariant contribution of the $G$ action only comes from the projective complex.

Edit. Note that group homology is defined as the left derived functors  $L_i(\mathbf{Z}\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}[G]}(-))R.$ This is the same as taking the left derived functors $L_i((-)\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}[G]}R)\mathbf{Z}.$

Comment: One thing ,i read the definition of Homology with coefficients in Brown's Book , where he defines $H_*(G,R) =H_*(F \otimes_G R)$, where $F \otimes_G R \cong (F \otimes R)_{G} \cong \mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z} [G]} (F \otimes R) $, so im not sure that is the same thing you have there.

Comment: Yes, these are the same thing. Your functor $(-)_G$ takes coinvariants. For a module with trivial $G$ action it does nothing. Now also $(-)_G\cong \mathbf{Z}\otimes_G(-)$  as functors, where tensoring over $G$ means tensoring over the ring $\mathbf{Z}[G].$
If $F_{\bullet}$ is the free $\mathbf{Z}[G]$ resolution of $R$ you need to compute $\textrm{Tor}_i^{\mathbf{Z}[G]}(\mathbf{Z},R)$. Equivalently, you can take a free $\mathbf{Z}[G]$ resolution of $\mathbf{Z}$ and tensor with $-\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}[G]}R$ since both give the same answer.

Comment: Now your final equality follows by noting that $\mathbf{Z}\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}[G]}(F_{\bullet}\otimes R)\cong (\mathbf{Z}\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}[G]}(F_{\bullet})\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}[G]} R\cong (F_{\bullet})_G\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}[G]}R\cong  (F_{\bullet})_G\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}} R, $ where the last isomorphism is true since both sides have trivial $G$-action.

Comment: Oh yeah that works thanks alot !, sorry for the confusion i am little new to all of this.

Comment: no problem, hope it helped!